# Passing REINSTALLMODE to an MSI file

Tags: deployment, .net-2.0, windows-installer, vdproj

I am using VisualStudio2005 and a vdproj to create a simple MSI file.  I need to pass in the REINSTALLMODE property when I launch it.

I know this can be done via command line, like so:
`msiexec.exe /i foo.msi REINSTALLMODE=amus`

However, if a user chooses to click the msi directly (launching the wizard), the property is not passed.  Is it possible to do this via the VS and vdproj?

Some options I've investigated:

- When I build the MSI via VS, it also produces a setup.exe.  Is there a way to pass the REINSTALLMODE property through this maybe?
- I installed Orca, which allows me to view/edit the Property table of the MSI.  I could add it this way, but then I'd have to add it every time I do an MSI build.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, I can't find a way to set other MSI properties right in VStudio.

Nonetheless, one method that should work is this:

1. Use Orca to create a transform (MST) that only change the property REINSTALLMODE. (In short, you edit the property & save as a new transform, then use the "Generate Transform" command to create the MST.)
2. This transform can be applied directly to your MSI using the [MSITRAN.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370495%28VS.85%29.aspx) command (available in the same Windows Installer SDK where you found Orca).
3. You could either:
   (a) find a way to have Visual Studio always run your MSITRAN command immediately after the MSI build, or
   (b) just run your MSITRAN manually (from a batch file or such) after building but before testing.

Comment: (I should probably try to use WiX if this msi gets anymore complicated)

Comment: Indeed, WiX gives you access to all the complexities of Windows Installer. But it is a bit of a learning curve. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

I found a more automated way to do this.

Create a script named **add_reinstall_prop.vbs**(example) with the folowing:

```
set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
set o_installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
set o_database = o_Installer.OpenDatabase(objArgs(0), 1)
s_SQL = "INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) Values( 'REINSTALLMODE', 'amus')"
set o_MSIView = o_DataBase.OpenView( s_SQL)
o_MSIView.Execute
o_DataBase.Commit
```

Add a post-build event to your setup project calling the script with the following:

```
add_reinstall_prop.vbs $(BuiltOuputPath)
```

This will automatically add the desired entry to the built MSI. 
You can then check it with Orca to see the entry is now added automatically after build.

Comment: Thanks man it works like charm. I need to use double quotes for

add_reinstall_prop.vbs "$(BuiltOuputPath)"